# Deleting the only node in a list issues

Tags: c++

I am having issues with deleting nodes in my doubly linked list, it crashes when I try to delete a node when there is only 1 node in the list. It works well otherwise. Its been driving me crazy because everything I have tried seems to make it worse not better. Here is my delete functions before I started changing them to try and get it to work better.

```
void doublyLinked::DeleteLast(int value) {
    if (first == NULL)
        cout <<" ERROR: You cannot delete what is not there. Please Try again! "
             << endl <<endl;
    else {
        Node* toDelete = last;
        last = toDelete -> previous;
        last->next = NULL;

        delete toDelete;
    }// end else
}// end function Delete Last

//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
void doublyLinked::DeleteFirst(int value) {

    if (last == NULL)
        cout <<" ERROR: You cannot delete what is not there. Please Try again! "
             << endl <<endl;// end if

    else {
        Node* toDelete = first;
        first->next->previous = NULL;
        first = toDelete->next;

        delete toDelete;
    }//end else
}
```

Comment: -1 **Do provide a complete example**. In a (properly) doubly linked list any node is deleted in the same way as any other node, without any special cases. Which is much of the point. The given code does therefore not make much sense, and it's incomplete, we can't try it.

Comment: You will have an answer here , don't worry about . However , try to format your code in a way , so that others can read it , okay !

Comment: I will try that, whoknows. Thank you.

Comment: formatted using AStyle

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one entry, then first == last.  Thus:

```
last = toDelete -> previous;
last->next = NULL;
```

is bad because after the first line `last` is NULL ;

Same with:

```
first->next->previous = NULL;
```

in the DeleteFirst()

Assume any `next` or `previous` pointer might be NULL and only use it after you've checked.  Example:

```
if ( first->next && first->next->previous ) { first->next->previous= NULL ; }
```

Also note, your `DeteleLast` would need to modify `first` when deleting the last item.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add test, if `first == last`. If so, delete it, and set both to NULL. Example:

```
if( first == last ) {
        delete first;
        first = last = NULL;

        return;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I swear I had tried that during one of trial and error processes but I had it in the wrong order so it didn't work..But it works now! Thank you SO MUCH!!